# Django create several records at a time

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-database

I want to be able to create as many records as a user wants for a database table in a single form.

For example, there will be some inputs for the data required for a record and at the end of the line a "+" button that would make a new line of inputs appear. There should be no limit to the number of lines and when the user clicks on the single submit button, all of the records would be inserted.

Thing is : I don't know how to make a new line appear dynamically, I suppose I have to use jquery for that but I'm kind of a newbie :)
And I don't know how I can iterate through all the lines dynamically added.

If someone can point to an example or something, it'd save me a lot of hair pulling !

EDIT :

By following this [blog post](http://stellarchariot.com/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/#comment-293) I managed to do that. I have one last problem which is : when I try to insert several records at one time, it keeps the last one fine, but the previous ones are considered empty. It tells me that the fields are required, I fill them up and click on save and only then it saves them allright.

Maybe I'll ask a new question for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

> I suppose I have to use jquery for that

That can also work.

> And I don't know how I can iterate through all the lines dynamically added.

You'll get all the fields of the form (all of them) in your `request.POST` object.  If you use a formset, it will largely be handled by the form's `clean()` and `save()` methods.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that as soon as I can. Do you know if it's easy to dynamically add a form in the formset ?

Comment: So I can display multiple lines using a formset. The thing I don't quite understand is how I can iterate through each line to save a new record. I'm using regular formset not inherited from my model, if I understand correctly it's a bit different